# How to Style Each Symbol in Header

Tags: html, css, symbols

I'm playing around with styling symbols and want to try to style this header by giving each of the dots between the letters the colors of the actual FRIENDS logo. I wanted to know what would be the best way to do this. Can symbol colors be changed in HTML? If yes, is making `p` tags with different ID's the only way to style the dots? Here is the header:

```
<header> F&#8226;R&#8226;I&#8226;E&#8226;N&#8226;D&#8226;S </header>
```

**Note:** I would only like to use HTML and CSS to do this not Javascript or JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `span` tags which have `class` attributes and according CSS rules for the classes (which can be reused)

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.yellow {
  color: yellow;
}

.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.brown {
  color: brown;
}
```

```html
<header> F<span class="red">&#8226;</span>R<span class="blue">&#8226;</span>I<span class="green">&#8226;</span>E<span class="yellow">&#8226;</span>N<span class="orange">&#8226;</span>D<span class="brown">&#8226;</span>S </header>
```

Comment: I was just going to say I meant the symbols and not the letters but you fixed it right away. Just to clarify, aren't span tags going to make new lines? I'm confused on why the code runner here doesn't put everything on new lines @Johannes

Comment: no, span tags are inline by default, that's why they are the first choice for situations like this

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you surround each symbol with a `<span>` tag and target it individually with an "id".

It'd look something like this:
`<header> F<span id="red">&#8226;</span>R<span id="blue">&#8226;</span>I&<span id="green">#8226;</span>E<span id="yellow">&#8226;</span>N<span id="orange">&#8226;</span>D<span id="brown">&#8226;</span>S </header>`

You wouldn't want to use `<p>` tags to style the symbols because they would create new lines between each letter.

Answer (score 0):

Just put every later or desired sign into span tag and color it with class or inline style attributes as seen on last two latters in code.

```css
.red{
color: red;
}
.blue{
color: blue;
}
.green{
color: green;
}
.brown{
color: brown;
}
.orange{
color: orange;
}
```

```html
<header> <span class="red">F</span>&#8226;<span class="green">R</span>&#8226;<span class="brown">I</span>&#8226;<span class="blue">E</span>&#8226;<span style="color:yellow">D</span>&#8226;<span style="color:gray">S</span> </header>
```